# Need to store three users login data in session variables using same browser

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I need to know how to allow three different users to login into the same site using three different tabs on same browser.

Comment: You could store session id in url query. But in this case user session will only last until the tab is closed. Any persistent storage  (e.g. cookies) will only allow you to maintain a single session.

Comment: Hello leonid, I want to implement this in cakephp. I need to store session id in url of home page. so I tried to do this in routes.php, which didn't work.Can you suggest me any alternative way to do this??

Comment: Why did you tag your question with `node.js` tag if you work with `php`?

Comment: My apologies. Using stack overflow for the first time, hence didn't understant the concept of tags. I have changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to set different session keys in AuthComponent configuration. For example:

```
AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Administrator'; // for administrators

AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Manager'; // for managers

AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Users'; // for users
```

Take in mind that you will need to check and set what session key to use. I am just pointing how to save it in different keys. You can find more information about AuthComponent in [CakePHP Official Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

Comment: But still he will be not abble to stay logined in as three different users in the same time

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. All the three id's are accessible in all the tabs of browser. Unable to understand who has logged in in which tab. Is there is any way to limit the session to a particular tab?? Or identifying which tab we are currently working on?

Comment: You may use one prefix for each tab and store $sessionkey based on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does help me to certain extend. If I come across any difficulty while implementing this, I will keep on sharing  it with you.